# How to use MDX to get T-SQL like, single axis, leaf level results

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I am facing a situation where I have to replicate a report based on relational database with a report retrieving data from an OLAP cube.
The report I am trying to replicate displays leaf level data like the following:

Account | PersonID | Product | SalesQTY

When I try to replicate this report with MDX the problem is that Account and Person dimensions have too many members , so when I crossjoin them the system goes out of memory. I tried using FILTER() to narrow down a little bit but without success.

Note that there is only one axis.
How can I get the same result with the T-SQL query using MDX without performance issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN() function

Comment: This is old - now people use `NON EMPTY` in their select clause, or wrap `NonEmpty` around a set - which might be a set of tuples created by a cross-join